# Apple Preview encoding #

Tags: macos, pdf, preview, catalina

I have a [PDF file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UbkZl4fhDBMlbMPw8zvMq7Vas6Zm7CE7/view?usp=sharing) generated from a gDoc including links with jump marks. Example link:

https://digitaleneuordnung.de/blog/lean-management/#3M

Opening the generated PDF in Acrobat Reader everything works fine. Opening the same file in Preview, the hashtag in the link is replaced with *%23* and opening the links in a browser end in a 404.

Is there anything I can do so that the links including jump marks also work fine if opened / clicked from the Preview?

Comment: Catalina 10.15.1, Preview v 11.0

Comment: Thanks. Does not change anything, same result. Can you open the PDF and confirm that the first link ("3M") opens correctly? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UbkZl4fhDBMlbMPw8zvMq7Vas6Zm7CE7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks. So not a local problem. Any ideas?

Comment: I have to test some things first...

Comment: @AndreasDiehl: I tested it in my MBP with the link you have shared. I downloaded the pdf and checked on the preview too. There is no issue. How about updating your macOS to 10.15.2 and check it.

Comment: Thanks for the proposals. I have updated to macOS to 10.15.2. The issue persists

Comment: The PDF works for me on Mojave. Technically, using URL encoding of that sort should still be a valid URL. So it's a weird problem that probably requires a lot of investigation. It might be worth flagging with Apple.